Why is the extension field polynomial for AES irreducible but not primitive?
The AES standard (FIPS 197 page 8) states that multiplication over GF($2^8$) is done using the polynomial $m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$. This polynomial is irreducible. However, it is not a primitive polynomial over GF($2^8$), but rather of order 51. Neither in FIPS 197 nor in "The Design of Rijndael, AES — The Advanced Encryption Standard" I have found a motivation or explanation for why not to choose a primitive polynomial.
Thus my question is: What are the advantages / disadvantages of choosing an irreducible but not primitive polynomial versus choosing a primitive polynomial for multiplication in GF($2^8$) from a security perspective? For example, one could have chosen the primitive polynomial $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$. Does it make the cipher more robust against attacks?
Addendum:
In "AES Proposal: Rijndael" page 5 it is stated that
"It follows that the set of 256 possible byte values, with the EXOR as addition and the
multiplication defined as above has the structure of the finite field GF($2^8$)."
However, as far as I understand, in order to generate the multiplicative group of some field GF($q$), the primitive polynomial (or generator) must be of order $q - 1$ (please correct me, if I'm wrong here). Thus, how can it be, that the standard states, that the field structure is GF($2^8$)? What is the field resp. group structure of the AES extension field?

If it's not primitive (i.e. not of order $q-1$), it doesn't generate the field by multiplication, but it still generates the field by multiplication and addition.
